# How do I save a list in a .py file?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am reading the contents of a normal text file and then trying to save it in  a .py file as a list variable.

Initially what I tried was reading the contents of the file and then storing them in a list. Then I wrote them to a .py file by myself.

```
>>> f = open("word.txt","r+")
>>> string = f.read()
>>> string = (string.split("\n")) #checkpoint
>>> string = "\',\' ".join(string)
>>> len(string)
147636
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open("word.py","w")
>>> f.write("word = [\'")
>>> f.write(string)
>>> f.write("\']")
>>> f.close()
```

However when I try to use `import word`
I get the following error

> SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Is there any way I can save the list string at the checkpoint shown into .py file?

Comment: fyi you could do `f.write('word = ' + repr([string]))`

Comment: `.py` files are usually reserved for python scripts or modules.  You should have a look at numpy's [`save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) method.

Comment: or, pickle (though that can be dangerous). Or better yet, `json.dump` and `json.load`.

Comment: Or just save the string: `with open('word.saved.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(string))`

Comment: What data transfer problem are you trying to solve?  Why is it important to save and reload this as a list?

Comment: Just close the file object `f.close()`and check the code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pprint.html) might help. `pprint()` uses `repr()` to take care of any string-escape requirements (for example, a lone `'` embedded in the middle of the string.) It also takes a `stream=` parameter to redirect the output to a file.

You could equally well  use `repr(string)` instead of `pprint(string)`. I chose `pprint()` to split the result onto multiple lines.

Note also the use of `with open(...) as ...:`. This automatically closes the file when the indent block is exited.

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('word.txt') as f:
    string = f.read().split('\n')
with open('word.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('word = ')
    pprint(string, stream=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you used `import` on a file that is *not* a Python module.  You cannot write out a list value as a text and simply regain it as a list value through a trivial input operation.

When you `import` your value, Python tries to parse it as a code file.  Somewhere in the file you wrote is a triple-quote (opening) without a closing triple-quote.  Python hit end of file and finally realized that there's no end to the string.  This is where it gets mad: you lied to Python.  You told it this would be a legal module, and gave it something that's not even legal *tokens*.  :-)

You need to find a viable way to transfer that list value.  I can't suggest anything here, because you haven't described the higher-level problem.